# If $E\{X\} = a E\{y\}$ and a > 1, what does this imposes on the value of $P\{X < Y\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Imagine having two random variables (distribution unknown), and we know that $E\{X\} = aE\{y\}$ and $a>1$. What can we interpret of the value of $P\{X<Y\}$ in this case? Can any interpretion be achieved?

In the question I am currently trying to solve, E{X} = 50 * E{Y}, and P{X<Y}=0.98. I'm trying to understand how is this feasible. I cannot prove nor disprove if any pair of random variables exists that satisfy these conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(X=0, Y=1)=0.98$ and $P(X=49a, Y=0) = 0.02$. Then $E[X]=0.98a$ and $E[Y] = 0.98$, and $P(X<Y)=0.98$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y=1$ (a.s.), pick $\gamma\in(0,1]$, and let $$X=\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{\gamma}&\mathbb{P}\gamma \\
0&\mathbb{P}(1-\gamma)
\end{cases}$$ where "$v\quad\mathbb{P}p$" means $v$ occurs with probability $p$.  Then $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{a}{\gamma}\cdot\gamma=a=a\mathbb{E}[Y]$$  Also, $\frac{a}{\gamma}\geq a>1$, so $$\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=\mathbb{P}[X<1]=1-\gamma$$  By choosing $\gamma$ appropriately, you can make $\mathbb{P}[X<Y]$ be whatever you want.

On the other hand, in order to make $\mathbb{P}[X<Y]$ be large, you need $\gamma$ to be small, so that $\frac{a}{\gamma}$ is very large.  You can rule out this sort of situation if you have some sort of bound on $X$.